# Docker for window giving message-Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, window, docker-machine

I have been trying to setup Docker for window machine and to run Asp.Net core 2.0 application in the Docker. I have setup below items.

1. Widow 10.
2. Visual Studio 2017, Community version.
3. Installed Core 2.0.

I have created a sample Asp.Net Core2.0 application and chosen Docker to run this application.

Below are the details -

1. Default project setup reference image-
   [Asp.Net core2.0 project setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtAoS.png)
2. [Docker run status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOjWR.png)

Below is the details for the timeout issue.

```
   Time out has expired and the operation has not been completed.
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus desiredStatus, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Docker.Backend.Processes.WindowsDockerDaemon.TryToStartService(String args, Dictionary`2 env) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\Processes\WindowsDockerDaemon.cs:line 138
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Windows.DoStart(Settings settings, String daemonOptions) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Windows.cs:line 200
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Windows.Start(Settings settings, String daemonOptions) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Windows.cs:line 78
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Register>b__0(Object[] parameters) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line 47
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.Nam
```

Can anyone suggest what could be issue for the timeout, I have tried and reset the docker

Comment: Have you started the 'Docker for Windows' app?It needs to be runnning. When Docker is running, the Docker whale is displayed. By default, the Docker whale icon is placed in the Notifications area. If it is hidden, click the up arrow on the taskbar to show it.

Comment: @alwayslearning thanks for the quick response, can you please suggest where to check, I am adding a screen shot for the reference. I am not able to add the screen shot, i have run the Docker terminal  from below path -C:\Users\jitendra\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Docker and reset all settings but still getting timeout error

Comment: As a first step, can you try and run the 'hello world' sample described here - https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#explore-the-application-and-run-examples
Does it run without any errors?

Comment: Hi have you checked the [system requirements](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#what-to-know-before-you-install) ? I encountered the same issue and I found that my machine use Windows 10 Home which is not supported yet

Comment: This will sound dumb. But I got this same error: Docker for Windows installed on a Windows 10VM running on VMware Fusion on a Mac. Quitting docker, and rerunning as Administrator got it to run for me.

Comment: Did you try my solution? and check is this solution, resolve your problem or not?

Answer (score 3):

I think maybe we have same problem

After many month, I found my problem

As you can see in [Crash while switching from Linux to Windows containers](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/11899) , My problem is one bug from Docker Desktop, that panic.txt is `readonly` after I change this from [forums docker guideline](https://forums.docker.com/t/error-message-when-trying-to-switch-to-windows-container/113809/10?u=soroshsabz)

The short answer is

1. Go to C:\ProgramData\Docker (Or any other location that data-root locate to it)
2. Right click on panic.txt → Properties
3. Uncheck ‘Read-Only’

My problem is resolved (very very thanks to [Tomas Slaman](https://forums.docker.com/u/tomasslaman/summary))

Comment: Can confirm, this solved my issue. Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue. We had to uninstall docker for Windows, and re-install. But this time we did not check the box (on the installation screen) which said "enable windows containers". So we just did next -> next which means Linux containers will be used instead of Windows, even though installation is being done on a Windows machine. Installation and launch were successful after that.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this and thought it necessary to confirm if virtualization is enabled on my system, as it being disabled could be the problem. Apparently, that was my problem.

So basically, since I had Hyper-V turned on already under "Turn Windows Features on or off" I simply ran the script on windows power-shell in admin mode:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
```

This forced a restart, after which I was fine.

Here is a reference guide to enabling on windows-10: 
https://thebackroomtech.com/2019/03/11/how-to-enable-virtualization-in-windows-10/

Hope this helps.